# Capacitor Firebase log in with Microsoft in ionic app on mobile device (iOS), invalid token

Tags: angular, firebase, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm using https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/tree/main/packages/authentication to log with 3 providers, Google, Microsoft and Apple. I'm also using the firebase SDK with the @angular/fire package to communicate with the Firestore DB.

For Google and Apple, after the initial login, i'm doing a "signInWithCredentials"  (angularfire method) with the token that i get back from the native layer - via native pop'up windows, and i am then signed in to Firebase in the JS SDK and i can access the DB.

The problem is Microsoft. For this provider, there is no native window that pops open, it's just a custom Safari browser window that opens on top of my original browser window, that houses the app. I can sign in fine in that window and i'm then redirected back to my app, from the sign in window. I am receiving a token when that happens.

When i try to do a "signInWithCredentials" with that token, Firebase is giving me an "invalid IdP token" error.

I'm using a standalone component for the app, and i'm initializing the Firebase app like so:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: [
            importProvidersFrom(
                 provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
                 provideAuth(() => {
                     return initializeAuth(getApp(), {
                        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
                     });
                 }),
            )
]})
```

The login code is this:

```
const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithMicrosoft();

const msprovider = new OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
const mscredential = msprovider.credential({idToken: result.credential?.idToken});
const auth = getAuth();

await signInWithCredential(auth, mscredential).then(async (data) => {console.log('some success message')}); // this fails with the "invalid IdP response/credential.."
```

This is in effect a redirect login, in app. I can't do a popup login (another firebase error, which i think is normal since popup are blocked by default in all browsers) nor a full browser redirect login, because that opens the browser app and, after sing in, it redirects back inside the browser app, not to my original app that opened the browser.

The only think different that i'm doing is, in a normal browser environment i'm logged in automatically, since the plugin uses the JS SDK there, by default. I appreciate any suggestions or clarifications. Thank you.